# Image of a compact interval under a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the following assertion : Assume that $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ are compact real intervals, and assume that $f$ is a continuous real valued function defined on $I_{1}$ such that $f(I_{1})\supset{I_{2}}$. Prove that there exists a compact sub-interval $I'_{1}$ of $I_{1}$ such that $f({I'_{1}})={I_{2}}.$

I was thinking along the following lines. Assume that ${I_{2}}^{\circ}$ is the interior of $I_{2}$. Then since $f$ is continuous $f^{-1}({{I_{2}}^{\circ})}$ must be open in the interior of ${I_{1}}^{\circ}$, and it must therefore be the mutually disjoint union of open segments. Am trying to prove that the image of a maximal open segment in this inverse image must be ${I_{2}}^{\circ}$, and then use continuity to prove that the closure this maximal open segment works as $I'_{1}$. Is there a simpler way to see this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is true?

Comment: It is a remark in a paper on dynamical systems that I am trying to work through. So it must be true-as the paper was presumably refereed by someone before it got published! Do you have a counter example?

Comment: I thought I did but I was wrong.

Comment: I do, however, have an example that shows "the image of a maximal open segment in the inverse image" will actually *not* give the correct answer, so your proof technique breaks down at that step.

Comment: That is useful.

Comment: Because of your remark, am thinking of a different approach. Let $I_{2} = [c, d]$. Then ${f^{-1}}(c) = A$ and ${f^{-1}}(d) = B$ must be disjoint compact subsets of $I_{1}$. If $ A < B$, then we take the largest element in $A$ and the smallest in $B$ and appeal to the intermediate value theorem to conclude that the image of $[A, B]$ should be $[c, d]$. The case $A > B$ can be treated similarly I guess.

Comment: This assumes $c \neq d$, which isn't a hard extra case to parse out.

Comment: There is a typo in the above argument. $A$ and $B$ are sets. I meant to say the following. If $a$ is the largest element in $A$ and $b$ is the smallest element in $B$, then the image of $[a, b]$ under $f$ should be $[c, d]$ by the intermediate value theorem. If $c = d$, then $I'_{1}$ becomes the degenerate interval $\{{f^{-1}(c)}\}$ that consists of a single point.

Comment: Do you feel like sharing your example? No hurry!

Comment: I can't write it out as a function:  I've only drawn the graph.

Comment: I have to go to bed, but I think you're super close but not quite there yet.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I_1=[a_1,b_1].$ Let $I_2=[a_2,b_2].$

Let $\alpha =\max f^{-1}\{a_2\}.$

(I).If  $\exists y>\alpha\;(f(y)=b_2)$ then let $\beta =\min (\;[\alpha,b_1]\cap f^{-1}\{b_2\}\;).$ And let $I'_1=[\alpha,\beta].$

(II). If $\neg (\exists y>\alpha\;(f(y)=b_2))$ then let $\beta =\max (\;[a_1,\alpha]\cap f^{-1}\{b_2\}\;)$ and let $\alpha^*=\min (\;[\beta,\alpha]\cap f^{-1}\{a_2\}\;).$ And let $I'_1=[\beta,\alpha^*].$

We have $f(I'_1)\supset I_2$. I will leave it to you to use the intermediate value property of $f$ to show that if $x\in I'_1$ then $(f(x)<a_2\lor f(x)>b_2)$ contradicts the definition of $I'_1$.

Comment: You must mean that either possibility $f(x') < {a_2}$ or $f(x') > {b_2}$ contradicts the definition of $I'_1$.

Comment: Yes.Thanks.  A typo. I made a correction.